# Definition of Functional Limits and Isolated Points

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $(X,d)$ and $(Y,w)$ be two metric spaces,  with A $\subseteq X $ and 
$f : A \to Y$.    Also, let p be a limit point of A.

I have the following definition for functional limits.
$lim_{x\to p}f(x) = L$
$\equiv $  $\forall \varepsilon>0, \exists \delta>0, ( \forall x \in A  (d(x,p)<\delta) \to w(f(x),L) <\varepsilon  )$        .

Now my question.
I'm trying to see what will happen if we re-define the functional limits as to include p to be any point in the closure of A ( not necessarily a limit point, but possibly an isolated point ).
I'm thinking that whenever we allow p to be an isolated point of A, the symbolic definition will crash and cause wierd results.   But i'm trying to see what will happen, more precisely.

What goes wrong in the definition whenever we allow p to be an isolated point ? I'm thinking that for those isolated points, the symbolic definition will become tautologically true, regardless of L, and hence f will be able to have ( by the old definition ) infinitely many limits as it approaches an isolated point in the domain of A.     Is that accurate ?   How is that true ?

P.S : I have a definition of an isolated point of A as a point such that there exists an open ball centered at it that contains no elements of A other than itself.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recognize your definition of a limit. The definition I know requires $x\ne p$, as below:

$$ \forall \varepsilon>0, \exists \delta>0, ( \forall x \in A\  (0<d(x,p)<\delta) \implies w(f(x),L) <\varepsilon  )$$

If $p$ is an isolated point of $A $ then the set $\{x \in A :  0<d(x,p)<\delta\}$ is empty for small $\delta$. As such, the requirement $w(f(x),L)<\varepsilon$ holds vacuously **no matter what $L$ is**. We lose uniqueness of limit; worse yet, since every real number of a limit of $f$ at $p$, the concept carries no information about $f$. I think this is enough to say that extending the definition was a bad idea.

---

The definition of *continuity* can be and is extended to isolated points;  every function is continuous at every isolated point of its domain. This is consistent with the topological characterization of continuity (preimages of open sets are open), which applies to every kind of domain, including those with isolated points.

Comment: In France the limit is usually defined with only $d(x,p)<\delta$, and not $0<d(x,p)<\delta$ (with the latter it is called "limite épointée").

Comment: Exactly, i also had limit defined with d(x,p)<δ and not 0<d(x,p)<δ.  Before i posted this question i was already thinking, if x would not be able to be equal to p, then i could see how the definition would crash, but since i had limit defined allowing x=p, i don't see how isolated points crash the definition. Should that mean that there's no problem allowing isolated points in my definition ?

Comment: @nerdy If you are using the French definition, everything's fine. The French limit of $f$ at an isolated  point is equal to the value of $f$ at that point.

Comment: Hm, that's wierd, i had it introduced with the restriction that p could not be an isolated point... Maybe the teacher comitted an error ?

Comment: @nerdy It's not an  error to impose such a restriction in the definition. There is no law that says every definition must be stated in greatest generality possible. On the contrary, one should carefully consider future uses of the definition, weighing any benefits of extra generality against any extra steps in proofs that this generality may cause.

Comment: I see what you are saying. Even though, p could be allowed to be a limit point in my definition withouth crashing it, maybe proving theorems with that definition would be harder.

Comment: Actually, Care Bear, i'm thinking here that even with my definition ( What you call french definition ), if i allow p to be an isolated point, the antecedent of the implication automatically becomes false, and hence the whole implication becomes true, regardless of the L.

Comment: @nerdy Since $x=p$ qualifies for $d(x,p)<\delta$, the implication requires $w(f(p),L)<\epsilon$. For all $\epsilon$. Hence $f(p)=L$.

Comment: I had it confused, thanks for the clarification again.

Comment: I came back to it again because i'm having the definition of one-sided limits ( left and right limit ) which is pretty close to the definition of functional limits ( it also allows the distance to be 0 ). I was thinking whether any point is allowed ( even points that are not limit points of the domain by the right or left or isolated points ) for lateral limits and i guess the conclusion is that it also holds for any kind of point of A ( isolated point, points that are not right/left limits, etc ) because of the mechanism you already introduced. Is it correct ?

Comment: Btw, my definition for the left-limit of f as x tends to p is exactly equal to the one described in my post, except that the antecedent of the implication becomes $\forall x \in ( A \cap( p-\delta,p) ) $ rather than $\forall x \in ( A \cap(p-\delta,p+\delta) ) $

Comment: @nerdy  Notice that $x\ne p$ in $\forall x \in A \cap( p-\delta,p)$. Therefore, if $p$ is an isolated point of $A$, the implication becomes true regardless of $L$.